# Formatting Layout in Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, layout, format

I'm trying to create an Android app whose home screen has three buttons. I'm using the program Eclipse and it automatically gives the buttons a horizontal linear layout. I'd like a vertical linear layout. While it is easier to code and format the buttons in XML, I really want all my code to be in Java. I've been looking through several sites for directions on how to format parameters such as gravity and weight in Java, but I'm stuck. Here are some examples of what I've found:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java

and

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html

They all give me errors and I understand that it's because I'm not using words that have 'J' anything or 'GridData'.

I've been trying to change some words in these codes so they can match my code, but I'm getting stuck. I think I'm just using the wrong words. 
Here's one way I tried:

My code:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(ll);
Button bAnalyze = new Button(this);
bAnalyze.setText("Analyze");
ll.addView(bAnalyze);
```

What I added:   ll.setOrientation(vertical);

This is my first week of learning Java and I have trouble with the language, as you can probably tell.If anyone could provide me with some code to try or suggestions, that'd be amazing.

Comment: try `ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will recommend you to follow [this tutorial.](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-layout/)

And for linear layout its:

```
  LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  
  ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); //orientation 
  ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  //setting width and height
  ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);  //setting the gravity
  ll.addView(label);  //adding a view..
  ll.addView(pic);  
  setContentView(ll);  //applying the layout to the activity
```

Comment: thank you! It works great and the tutorials will be very helpful

Comment: @user2442455 your welcome...but a tick or an up vote to my answer would be great:)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are trying the designing part in the java code.
As far as possible try and keep the design part of your application and the working logic of all the components of your application separate.

It helps to keep the designing and the coding of your application separate, so that it becomes easier for you to edit it at the maintenance phase(you don't have to spend much time distinguishing between the two when going through it).

Comment: It's part of the challenge my instructor has given us- to do as much coding in Java as possible, opposed to XML. We will still have XML code, this is part of 'exploring' Java